# What is the difference between size and height/width for tables?

Tags: matlab

I'm examining the `height` and `width` functions for tables in MATLAB.  Take `height` for example, in the documentation:

> `H = HEIGHT(T)` returns the number of rows in the table `T`.
>   `HEIGHT(T)` is equivalent to `SIZE(T,1)`.

Yet, when you inspect the code with `edit height`, it appears to call some class method `h = t.nrows;`.

A similar situation occurs for `width`. What is the difference, if any, between these functions?

Comment: "WIDTH(T) is equivalent to SIZE(T,2)" from the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in fact the same thing.  However, the `nrows` attribute for the number of rows (and subsequently the `nvars` attribute for the number of columns) for `table`s is actually a private attribute and we can't access it in the global workspace.  It is only accessible locally when you call `table`-based methods themselves.

Here's a running example.  I'll load in a table of patients data from MATLAB that comes with the environment:

```
T = readtable('patients.dat');
```

This is a 100 x 10 table of data.  Now let's try and access the `nrows` attribute:

```
>> T.nrows
Unrecognized variable name 'nrows'.
```

Nope.... doesn't work.  However, if you look at the source of `height` as you say, there's only one line of code on line 10 of the function: `h = t.nrows;` where `t` is the input `table` and `h` is the output argument.  Therefore, let's put in a breakpoint at this line of the `height` function, we'll then call `height` and let MATLAB stop at this point then let's actually try calling the `nrows` attribute again:

```
>> dbstop in height at 10
>> o = height(T);
10  h = t.nrows;    
K>> t.nrows

ans =

   100

K>> dbquit;
>> dbclear all;
>>
```

We first put in a breakpoint inside the `height` function right at line 10, we call `height` and we see that it stops right at line 10 in the function.  Next we try and call the `nrows` attribute for the table and lo-and-behold it does work.  I don't need to see anything more, so use `dbquit` to quit debugging mode, then clear all breakpoints by doing `dbclear all;`

Conceptually, there is no difference.  My guess with `nrows` and `nvars` is because they want to minimize any function calls being made in the class to make this fast.  `size` is a function call and so having attributes that directly give you the rows and columns of your table are faster than using a function to return these for you.  Another reason could be that `size` (natively) is only for numeric arrays.  You need to create custom behaviour if you have objects that aren't numeric and so `nrows` and `nvars` is a way of encoding this behaviour. In fact, if you examine the source for `size` specifically for the `table` method, you will see that `nrows` and `nvars` are being used to return the right numbers for you... again this is all speculative.  What you should take away from this is that you should just use `height` and `width` and interpret their results as if you were calling `size` on numeric arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. So is your hypothesis that `height` and `width` only improve speed?

Comment: @Alex I would say so... that or another reason I have is because `size` is only defined for numeric arrays.  If you create custom objects, like a `table`, you would need to implement your own methods for determining the height and width and so `nrows` and `nvars` is a way of encoding this behaviour.

Comment: You are quite correct, the table method `size` actually calls `nrows` and `nvars`.

Comment: @Alex well look at that! I looked at the source of `size` myself just now too.